# How to connect a class in one package with a class in another package?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, package-diagram

So that I can connect them in my package diagram. I'm using eclipse as IDE by the way.

Comment: What do you mean by connect? Create an association between them?

Answer (score 0):

The package diagram does not have all elements of the class diagram. So, you'll have to include some class diagram elements into your toolbox or palette or what you have as a source of elements. It is allowed by the UML standard.

Or make it as a class or object diagram. There you have all class diagram elements and packages, too.

Either way you'll get something as:

[image]